# use std::next_permutation with 2D Array

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

I want to print all the permutation of array `AAA`. I am unable to figure out the second argument of function `std::next_permutation`?

```
#include <algorithm>

char AAA[4][4] = {"abc","123","ABC"}; 

do
{
    printf("%s %s %d\n",AAA[0],AAA[1],AAA[2]);

}   while( std::next_permutation( AAA, ???? ));
```

Should it be `&AAA[3]` or something else?

Comment: With `char*`, you will compare address, use `std::string AAA[]` instead.

Comment: BTW, in ascii, `'1' < 'A'` and `'A' < 'a'`, so you should initialize to `{"123", "ABC", "abc"}` to iterate on all permutations.

Comment: Not true, Jarod42.   Since the sort order is based on comparing addresses, not the data pointed at, this will actually loop over all iterations.    Although, admittedly, that is probably more good luck than good planning by the OP - using an array (or container) of `std::string` requires sorting first, since the sort order is based on the data in the strings, not their address.

Answer (score 0):

It would be

```
 while( std::next_permutation( std::begin(AAA), std::end(AAA)));
```

or (more prosaically, if you know `AAA` has exactly `4` elements)

```
 while( std::next_permutation( AAA, AAA + 4));
```

It would probably be advisable for `AAA` to be an array of `std::string` or a `std::vector<std::string>`, although that will require sorting if the loop is to go across  all permutations.

And it will make C++ people flinch a little less if you `std::cout` to stream output, rather than using `printf()`.